# Is my function wrong? (New to javascript)

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict"

function fillTable() {
    let job = document.getElementById("items").value;
    let timeStamp = document.getElementById("when").value;


    let tr = document.createElement('tr');

    let td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    let td2 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

    td1.innerHTML = job;
    td2.innerHTML = timeStamp;


    document.getElementById('ListTable').appendChild('tr');
}
```

This is the error I get. "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'"

From my understanding this is an error we get when there is a type mismatch like when I try to append a string directly to the parentnode. Can someone help me out here because I don't see a type mismatch or I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: On your last line, `'tr'` is a string, not an element.

Comment: You should pass the `tr` variable you created into the line `document.getElementById('ListTable').appendChild('tr');` instead of the `'tr'`

Comment: @Amy Thanks a lot! I knew it was going to be something obvious, appreciate the help. ^ ^

Comment: @Gunnarhawk Thanks a lot man, I mixed it up because of the way I named my variable ugh

Answer (score 0):

Passed a string 'tr' (document.getElementById('ListTable').appendChild('tr');) instead of the node object tr while appending the table row to the parent node table.

Answer (score 0):

```
"use strict"

function fillTable() {
  let job = document.getElementById("items").value;
  let timeStamp = document.getElementById("when").value;


  let tr = document.createElement('tr');

  let td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  let td2 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

  td1.innerHTML = job;
  td2.innerHTML = timeStamp;


  document.getElementById('ListTable').appendChild(tr);
 }
```